# NSBundle(forClass:) changed in iOS 9.3 SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, uikit

I extracted some UI elements into a different framework then my main app.

At some point I load a storyboard programmatically. Both, the class containing that code and the storyboard to load, are inside the framework. Previously I did that like this:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: bundle)
```

However, after I updated Xcode to 7.3 (with the new iOS 9.3 SDK), my app is crashing there because `NSBundle(forClass:)` is actually returning the main bundle of my app now (instead of the framework's bundle). I now have to use `NSBundle(identifier:)` to work around this.

Is this intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There were some changes made to `NSBundle.h` in iOS 9.3, none of which should have broken this behavior.  Still investigating... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS93APIDiffs/Objective-C/Foundation.html

Comment: @JAL: Thanks! Do you have the same issue?

Comment: Nope, just trying to answer your question ;)

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening for me as well. I have a class named `LibraryManager` in a framework. One of its methods uses `NSBundle(forClass:)`. If I use `self.dynamicType`, I end up with the app's main bundle. If I use `LibraryManager.self`, I end up with the framework's bundle, which is what I want. Oddly enough, using `self.dynamicType` in the class' `init` does return the correct thing.

Comment: @Rudedog you can submit your comment as an answer, works great.